# How to call a stored procedure that returns dynamic columns in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

There is a stored procedure that executes `exec` command and returns some columns. Columns and number of them are varied. How can I call this stored procedure from Entity Framework?

Comment: This is a **horribly bad** design - and EF doesn't support it (and that's a good thing!). Your stored procedure should be **stable** and return one "shape" of data only - these "do it all" procedures are just really really ugly to use and to maintain - I'd strongly recommend **against** this practice!

Comment: Well I basically agree, but whether a design is good or bad is always subjective, e.g. DOES depend on the context.

Comment: @Bart: I totally agree with you. we can not say it a bad design, although it might be a functional requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a ComplexType in the EntityFramework and then call the stored procedure:

```
public ObjectResult<yourComplextype> MyMethod()
{
 return _dbContext.usp_Yourprocedure();
}
```

Comment: Sure - but if the "shape" of the data changes with each call - what is this complex type going to be??

Comment: is the number of columns are changes

Comment: @marc_s I think we can also call the sp without using ComplexType